# Do I conserve memory in MATLAB by declaring variables global instead of passing them as arguments?

Tags: matlab, memory-management

I am new to MATLAB, it wasn't in the job description and I've been forced to take over for the person who wrote and maintained the code my company uses. Life's tough.

The guy from which I'm taking over told me that he declared all the big data vectors as `global`, to save memory. More specifically, so that when one function calls another function, he doesn't create a copy of the data when he passes it over.

Is this true? I read [Strategies for Efficient Use of Memory](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/index.html?/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/brh72ex-25.html), and it says that

> When working with large data sets, be aware that MATLAB makes a temporary copy of an input variable if the called function modifies its value. This temporarily doubles the memory required to store the array, which causes MATLAB to generate an error if sufficient memory is not available.

It says something very similiar in [Memory Allocation For Array #Function Arguments](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/brh72ex-2.html#brh72ex-13):

> When you pass a variable to a function, you are actually passing a reference to the data that the variable represents. As long as the input data is not modified by the function being called, the variable in the calling function and the variable in the called function point to the same location in memory. If the called function modifies the value of the input data, then MATLAB makes a copy of the original array in a new location in memory, updates that copy with the modified value, and points the input variable in the called function to this new array.

So is it true that using `global` can be better? It seems a little sloppy to blithely declare all the large data as `global`, instead of making sure that none of the code modifies its input argument. Am I wrong? Does this really improve RAM usage?

Comment: Why don't you monitor the RAM usage to see what's better? I don't think your question is different than any other performance ones. You need to profile your code. It seems like you can write two loops and test if a variable as a global or as a function's input is better when your code changes the input's data (if it does at all, because memory is only "doubled" when it does). Sorry for not giving the answer, but there are too many gotchas when performance matters.

Comment: Your absolutely correct, but I asked the question anyway, since I was worried that this was a matter of coding style and not just memory. Oh well...

Comment: Couple things that might help: "profile on -memory" will track allocation in the Matlab profiler. And if you're using R2008a+, new style "handle" objects can do pass by reference, which will conserve memory but have better scope control than globals.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my experience, provided that none of the code modifies the large data, memory usage is the same, regardless of whether you use a global variable or an input argument, just like the Matlab docs say. Further information is in this [blog post](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2006/05/10/memory-management-for-functions-and-variables/) by a MathWorks employee.

There is quite a bit of folklore on performance issues in Matlab and not all of it is right. The internals of Matlab have changed quite a bit. It may be that in a previous version it's better to use a global variable.

Comment: +1 and answer for coolness, for using Loren's blog, too. She's a user here! - http://stackoverflow.com/users/113700/loren

Answer (score 4):

This answer may be somewhat tangential, but an additional topic that bears mention here is the use of [nested functions](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f4-39683.html) to manage memory.

As has already been established in other answers, there is no need for `global` variables if the data you are passing to the function is not modified (since it will be passed by reference). If it *is* modified (and is thus passed by value), using a `global` variable instead will save you memory. However, `global` variables can be somewhat "uncouth" for the following reasons:

- You have to make a declaration like `global varName` everywhere you need them.
- It can be conceptually a little messy trying to keep track of when and how they are modified, especially if they are spread across multiple m-files.
- The user can easily break your code with an ill-placed [`clear global`](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/clear.html), which clears *all* global variables.

An alternative to `global` variables was mentioned in [the first set of documentation you cited](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/brh72ex-25.html): nested functions. Immediately following the quote you cited is a code example (which I've formatted slightly differently here):

```
function myfun

  A = magic(500);
  setrowval(400, 0);
  disp('The new value of A(399:401,1:10) is')
  A(399:401,1:10)

  function setrowval(row, value)
    A(row,:) = value;
  end

end
```

In this example, the function `setrowval` is *nested* inside the function `myfun`. The variable `A` in the workspace of `myfun` is accessible within `setrowval` (as if it had been declared `global` in each). The nested function modifies this shared variable, thus avoiding any additional memory allocation. You don't have to worry about the user inadvertently clearing anything and (in my opinion) it's a bit cleaner and easier to follow than declaring `global` variables.

Answer (score 3):

The solution seems a bit strange to me. As you found out already, it shouldn't have significant impact on the memory usage if the called function does not modify the data array. However, if the called function modifies the data array, there's a *functional* difference: In one case (making the data array global), the change has an impact on the rest of the code, in the other case (passing it as reference) the modifications are only local and temporary.

Answer (score 3):

I think you pretty much answered your own question, but a couple more references would be good here:

I made a video on this:

http://blogs.mathworks.com/videos/2008/09/16/new-location-and-memory-allocation/

Similar to what Loren spoke of here:

http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2006/05/10/memory-management-for-functions-and-variables/

-Dogu